# GTKMM - `WIDGET_REALIZED_FOR_EVENT (widget, event)'

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

We are working on a gtkmm24 application.  There's a long standing bug that if a user clicks too quickly on a Gtk::CellRendererCombo in a Gtk::TreeView the whole application locks up with a GTK Assert:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_event: assertion `WIDGET_REALIZED_FOR_EVENT (widget, event)' failed
```

This assert then repeats if you mouse anywhere over the application.

On the screen you get a gray box where the renderer combo should have "popped up":

[image]

My thought was that the error is caused by selecting another row's combo renderer while a previous selection was trying to finish rendering.  I've attempted all sorts of delays and blocks to not allow the user to select another row before the previous selection was "edited" or "canceled" but to no avail.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: That's not a lot to go on. Use this along with a debugger to get more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646510/causing-gtk-to-abort-on-assert